# Bootstrap 3 dropdown animations not showing first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this simple script:

```
var $dropdowns = $('.dropdown');
$dropdowns.hover(function()
{
    $(this).addClass('open');
    $(this).find('.dropdown-toggle').attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(200).slideDown(400);
}, function()
{
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(200).slideUp(400, function()
    {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
        $(this).parent().find('.dropdown-toggle').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
    });
});
```

It is supposed to animate all Bootstrap dropdowns on hover, but for some strange reason it doesn't work the first time; after that, all is well. Why is that?

I have also tried adding this `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle').dropdown('toggle');` at the end with no positive result.

As requested, here is the html for the navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="../php/content.php" target="_self">My cool website</a>
    </div>
    <div id="nav" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href>Caini<span class="caret"></span></a><ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu"><li><a href="../php/content.php?group=1&page=1">Istorie</a></li><li><a href="../php/content.php?group=1&page=2">Mancare</a></li><li><a href="../php/content.php?group=1&page=3">Comportament</a></li></ul></li><li class="active"><a href="../php/content.php?group=13&page=6">Monstrii</a></li><li><a href="../php/content.php?group=2&page=4">Pisici</a></li><li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href>Gaini<span class="caret"></span></a><ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu"><li><a href="../php/content.php?group=4&page=11">Cucurigu</a></li><li><a href="../php/content.php?group=4&page=9">Cotcodac</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="../php/new_group.php?add=true">+ Add a new group</a></li>            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please excuse my formatting, but that is php generated code.

After gon250's answer, I updated my code with the same result:

```
var $dropdowns = $('.dropdown');
$dropdowns.hover(function()
{
    $('.dropdown-toggle', this).trigger('click');
});

$dropdowns.on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e)
{
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(200).slideDown(400);
});

$dropdowns.on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(200).slideUp(400, function()
    {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
        $(this).parent().find('.dropdown-toggle').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
    });
});
```

This is the piece of code that worked for me; thanks to gon250.

```
var $dropdowns = $('.dropdown');
$dropdowns.hover(function()
{
    $('.dropdown-toggle', this).trigger('show.bs.dropdown');
}, function()
{
    $('.dropdown-toggle', this).trigger('hide.bs.dropdown');
});

$dropdowns.on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(200).slideDown(400, function()
    {
        $(this).parent().addClass('open');
        $(this).parent().find('.dropdown-toggle').attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
    });
});

$dropdowns.on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).find('li.active').length <= 0)
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(200).slideUp(400, function()
    {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
        $(this).parent().find('.dropdown-toggle').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
    });
});
```

Comment: Any JS console errors?

Comment: placed also the piece of html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a demo for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/e4tzdkLq/4/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      //Animation Slideup
      $('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e){
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown().delay(200);
      });
      //Animation Slidedown
      $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e){
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp().delay(400);
      });

    $('.dropdown').hover(function(){ 
      $('.dropdown-toggle', this).trigger('click'); 
    });
});
```

What I did is trigger bootstraps click event with a hover. I think is the best way.

I hope it's helps.

Comment: You kind of forgot that I wanted animations; anyway, I added them in the dropdown events, and the result is the same.

Comment: @Valdrinit Take a look now, I think it's working preoperly with the animations :)

Comment: Indeed it works very well in the demo, exept the slideup animation, which can be easily fixed like in my updated question. The best method by far. But on my machine, the first slidedown animation is still not shown.

Comment: @Valdrinit mmm for me and my mate is working the first time perfectly, so.. I have no idea what is happening in your machine. I'll check again, should be something wrong something in your code. :s

Comment: I have added the `delay` and still working.. http://jsfiddle.net/e4tzdkLq/4/ why you dont use the trigger?? I have updated it again.

Comment: I have found something that also works on my machine based on your answer. I will update the question. Thanks!

Comment: I found that triggering the click event was quite buggy when I clicked on a dropdown. I think the new hover function is a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

Just like in "hover out", your "hover in" function needs to toggle the classes once the animation is complete to behave properly.

```
var $dropdowns = $('.dropdown');
$dropdowns.hover(function()
{
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(250).slideDown(400, function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('open');
    $(this).parent().find('.dropdown-toggle').attr('aria-expanded', 'true');  
  });
}, function()
{
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(200).slideUp(400, function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
    $(this).parent().find('.dropdown-toggle').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
  });
});
```

**Live example**

http://www.bootply.com/YEgWx0DX08

Comment: Shouldn't you add the classes to the parent is the first case, also?

Comment: In truth, if you want the dropdown to close on "hover out", you don't even need to toggle the classes. http://www.bootply.com/Ue2n39KzD2 - But yes, it should be applied to the parent, this was just a copy paste from your original code. I'll update it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as you can see, I have already found something that works.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $dropdowns = $('.dropdown');
$dropdowns.hover(function()

.....

});
```

the script could be loaded too late.

Comment: I am so sorry, that was only a piece of my code. I am already doing this.

Comment: The import is in the head tag?

Comment: Is at the end of the body, where it's supposed to be.